# Discord.py Question with weird betting winnings

Tags: discord.py, embed, title

[image]

As the title suggests, I have some trouble with the titles of my betting command. Sometimes it doesn't show up, while at other times it shows up as something with a lot of 1's and 0's. I think it might be binary, but I don't know.
Code:
https://replit.com/@jsun3/Betting-cmd#main.py

Stacks was being annoying on formatting so I did it in replit.

Ceres' answer helped, but caused another error. When I won sometimes it counted -10 won(meaning i lost 10).
IMG:

[image]

New update for code:
https://replit.com/@jsun3/Betting-cmd#main.py

Comment: Note I might respond in like 10-14 hours because I'm going to sleep soon its late for me.

Comment: Can you show what error occurs?

Comment: Oh its you again! Uhhh its noy really an error, its more of a bug. Yes, I will upload a picture of it one 1 minute.

Comment: It should be there now

Comment: What did you invoke it with? I assume 10

Comment: yes i betted 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `amount` is a string, and in python you can multiply a string to repeat it. That is exactly what is happening.
Solve it with

```py
@client.command(aliases=["gamble"])  # ASSUME I HAVE CLIENT DEFINED BC IN MY REAL CODE IT IS DEFINED.
async def bet(ctx, amount: int = None):
```

Since discord.py implements type-converters for arguments, your amount is converted to an integer, and will be multiplied like one.

Comment: Oh ok I will try it out thank you so much.

Comment: it works but it causes something else, look at the post again.

Comment: The default multiplier (-1) is being used. The error is from your code logic, not from the answer

Comment: So should i change the default to 1? If i do, it get the opposite, losing is winning and winning sometimes is losing. So what should I do?

Comment: `if 2 <= you - me >= 4`. This should be `2 <= you - me <= 4` or it will only be executed when the difference is greater than 4